# How to log TLS session keys in HAProxy ala SSLKEYLOGFILE

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I'm trying to avoid using an `LD_PRELOAD`-based solution, and the haproxy documentation seems to imply it's possible to make an sslkeylog file without actually saying how.

I know the information can be sortof "made available" with [tune.ssl.keylog](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.9/configuration.html#tune.ssl.keylog) which has docs that talk about all the samples needed for a standard keylog file like `ssl_fc_server_traffic_secret_0` for `SERVER_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0`.

But then what? How do I setup a "log" output that will put each thing on its own line in the right format?

Comment: why does asking a question always magically give me the power to find the answer. searched on github for `tune.ssl.keylog` and found https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/e1c8bfd0ed960d3b3dec39e78ad75bec117912d0/dev/sslkeylogger/sslkeylogger.lua will post a proper answer later when I'm sure it works

Comment: Did it work????

Comment: @WillManley Thanks for reminding me, posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the hacky, awkward way I figured out how to do this. It's not great:

Create a lua file `sslkeylogger.lua`:

```lua
local function sslkeylog(txn)
    local fields = {
        CLIENT_EARLY_TRAFFIC_SECRET     = function() return txn.f:ssl_fc_client_early_traffic_secret()     end,
        CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET = function() return txn.f:ssl_fc_client_handshake_traffic_secret() end,
        SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET = function() return txn.f:ssl_fc_server_handshake_traffic_secret() end,
        CLIENT_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0         = function() return txn.f:ssl_fc_client_traffic_secret_0()         end,
        SERVER_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0         = function() return txn.f:ssl_fc_server_traffic_secret_0()         end,
        EXPORTER_SECRET                 = function() return txn.f:ssl_fc_exporter_secret()                 end,
        EARLY_EXPORTER_SECRET           = function() return txn.f:ssl_fc_early_exporter_secret()           end
    }

    local client_random = txn.c:hex(txn.f:ssl_fc_client_random())

    -- ensure that a key is written only once by using a session variable
    if not txn:get_var('sess.sslkeylogdone') then
        for fieldname, fetch in pairs(fields) do
            if fetch() then
                core.Warning(string.format('SSLKEYLOG:: %s %s %s\n', fieldname, client_random, fetch()))
            end
        end

        txn:set_var('sess.sslkeylogdone', true)
    end
end

core.register_action('sslkeylog', { 'http-req' }, sslkeylog)
```

This is modified from [the original](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/e1c8bfd0ed960d3b3dec39e78ad75bec117912d0/dev/sslkeylogger/sslkeylogger.lua) which I'm not sure ever worked. It logs all session keys as warnings, which should go to the regular HAProxy logs.

In the HAProxy config:

```
global
  tune.ssl.keylog on
  lua-load path/to/sslkeylogger.lua

frontend foobar
  http-request lua.sslkeylog
```

Then, you'll need to grab the logs (if they're in systemd, `journalctl -u haproxy`) and filter for only relevant log lines, and remove any timestamps or other info preceding the `EXPORTER_SECRET` and such. I can't be more specific because it depends on the logging setup. After doing that you'll have a file you can give to wireshark in combination with a packet dump to get the data.